# Disable notifications about Focus changes in Monterey?

Tags: notifications, monterey, focus

I like the Focus feature, but constant popups about "Focus: Work" / "Focus: Personal" when I switch the apps are very distracting.

Is there a way to disable those specific notifications? I don't want to disable ALL notifications, just the ones related to Focus changes

Comment: I would love an answer to this. It's irritating to get a pop up telling me that my scheduled do not disturb just turned on. Apple is interrupting me to tell me they're not going to interrupt me.